# Programmatically switch off Effects in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

My program needs to switch off as many visual effects in OSX as possible. E.g. the window shadow, transparency, etc. Is there any way to do that programmatically with objective c?

Comment: Are you talking about just for your app or are you trying to turn off effects for the whole system?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way you're going to be able to do this apart from macOS's accessibility features (which might or might not support what you're looking for—it certainly isn't user-level functionality) is to start messing around with private APIs and the system processes like the Window Server.